# Secondary axis in R which reflects percentiles

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis, axis-labels

I am trying to plot T norm scores (M=50, SD=10) and their relative percentiles with a secondary axis in R.

The data frame would look like this:

```
scale <- c("X","Y","Z") 
tScore <- c(55, 70, 43) 
percentile <- pnorm((tScore-50)/10) 
dataFrame <- data.frame(scale,tScore,percentile)
```

I tried to play around with the sec.axis function:

```
ggplot(dataFrame, aes(tScore,scale)) + geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous("T Norms", limits=(c(20,80)),
              sec.axis = sec_axis(~./ pnorm(dataFrame$tScore), name = "Percentile"))
```

I am trying to get the scale-Names (X,Y,Z) on the left on the y-axis and then three points - as the z-score and the percentile should be the same point - but with two y-axis, one in the top and one in the bottom. I tried in this example to not use the "percentile" column I created (because I would not know how) but to transform directly.
Unfortunately, it does not take pnorm as a way of transformation as it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% if I understand what you are trying to achieve. But to me that's sound like that you want a secondary x scale showing the percentiles for the t-scores plotted on the primary scale. In that case there is no need for a `trans`formation of the scale range. Instead you simply have to transform the labels:

```
library(ggplot2)

perc_label <- function(x) {
  x <- pnorm((x - 50) / 10)
  scales::label_number(accuracy = .001)(x)
}

ggplot(dataFrame, aes(tScore, scale)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous("T Norms",
    limits = c(20, 80),
    sec.axis = dup_axis(
      breaks = dataFrame$tScore,
      labels = perc_label, 
      name = "Percentile")
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Dear stefan, that is a very nice solution. Thank you so much. Actually, I was aiming at having the same breaks in the second axis in the top as in the bottom, though. Meaning at the line where it says 40 in the bottom, it should say 0.158 in the top. At the line of 60 it should say 0.841 and so on. So basically labeling the break lines instead of the specifiv value. Maybe you would know how to do this.

Comment: I just played around and figured it out by altering your code. When writing `breaks = waiver()` it works. Thanks again!

Comment: Great you figured it out yourself. Wasn't sure whether you want ticks for the data points or corresponding to the breaks of the primary axis. Just a remark: If you want to use the same breaks as for the primary scale then you could remove the `breaks` argument from `dup_axis`.

Comment: Very good comment as I just noticed that causes problems when I was adding additional breaks to the primary axis ;) Removing the breaks argument does it and also `derive()` instead of `waiver()`.